# Resizing images in Node Sharp.js

Tags: node.js, image, optimization, sharp

I am trying to take images from an input folder with 6 subfolders, optimise them accordingly and output them as WebP files all with different widths to be used as srcset images inside my website with the name convection for each file going from 1 and ascending until the list of images with the subfolder is completed. The code I have got helped with writing is

```
`
const fs = require('fs');
const sharp = require('sharp');

// Define the input directory
const inputDirectory = './input';

// Create an array to define categories and their settings
const categories = [
  { name: 'Important', minWidth: 1080, maxWidth: 2000, quality: 90 },
  { name: 'Gallery', minWidth: 800, maxWidth: 2000, quality: 80 },
  { name: 'Digitals', minWidth: 800, maxWidth: 2000, quality: 80 },
  { name: 'Contact', minWidth: 800, maxWidth: 1600, quality: 60 },
  { name: 'Misc', minWidth: 500, maxWidth: 1080, quality: 30 },
  { name: 'Loader', minWidth: 500, maxWidth: 1600, quality: 30 },
];

// Function to process images in a category
async function processCategory(category) {
  const inputFolder = `${inputDirectory}/${category.name}`;
  const outputFolder = `./output/${category.name}`;

  // Create the output folder if it doesn't exist
  if (!fs.existsSync(outputFolder)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(outputFolder, { recursive: true });
  }

  const files = fs.readdirSync(inputFolder);
  let imageNumber = 1;

  for (const file of files) {
    const inputPath = `${inputFolder}/${file}`;
    const image = sharp(inputPath);

    // Get image metadata
    const metadata = await image.metadata();

    // Check if the image width is within the specified range
    if (metadata.width >= category.minWidth && metadata.width <= category.maxWidth) {
      // Resize and optimize the image
      await image
        .webp({ quality: category.quality })
        .toFile(`${outputFolder}/${imageNumber}-${metadata.width}.webp`);

      imageNumber++;
    }
  }
}

// Main function to process all categories
async function processAllCategories() {
  for (const category of categories) {
    await processCategory(category);
  }
}

// Start the image processing
processAllCategories()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Image processing completed.');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error processing images:', error);
  });`
```

However it is only taking one image and resizing it to 900p and that's it!
Does someone out there know what tf is going on?
Thanks for your time, appreciate you reading this,
Luke :)

Answer (score 0):

you should try to put in an await when you're calling sharp(inputPath) ie:

```js
//...before

for (const file of files) {
    const inputPath = `${inputFolder}/${file}`;
    const image = await sharp(inputPath); // <-this line

    // Get image metadata
    const metadata = await image.metadata();

    // Check if the image width is within the specified range
    if (metadata.width >= category.minWidth && metadata.width <= category.maxWidth) {
      // Resize and optimize the image
      await image
        .webp({ quality: category.quality })
        .toFile(`${outputFolder}/${imageNumber}-${metadata.width}.webp`);

      imageNumber++;
    }
  }
//after..
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).